# Is there different between multiple `match` with single term in `should` vs a single `match` with multiple term in `should`?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there differences between the 2 below?

```
GET books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "description": {
              "query": "cat dog"
            }
          }
        }       
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
GET books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "description": {
              "query": "cat"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description": {
              "query": "dog"
            }
          }
        }       
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

From the results I see them as identical. The index document I use is as below

```
POST books/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{ "title": "Dogs", "description": "A fox jump over the lazy dog" }
{"index":{}}
{ "title": "Cats", "description": "Garfield the sleepy cat" }
{"index":{}}
{ "title": "Sleepy", "description": "Rest is important" }
{"index":{}}
{ "title": "Rich", "description": "Money is never enough" }
{"index":{}}
{ "title": "Pets", "description": "Dog and cat are friends" }
{"index":{}}
{ "title": "Character", "description": "Are you really a dog person?" }
```

The mapping is the default mapping

```
{
  "books" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your index mapping ?

Comment: I didn't explicitly set any mapping, it's the default dynamically set mapping.

Comment: sure, that way your text fields will use the standard analyzer, i will repro your issue, and will add example, meanwhile please go through my answer that will also makes thing clear

Answer (score 0):

it depends what analyzer your `description` field is using, if you are using the standard or whitespace analyzer which breaks the text on `whitespace`, it will be same.

You can use the [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to inspect what search time tokens is generated for your search term.

You should also note that default operator of [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) is `OR` and as explained in the same offical doc

> operator (Optional, string) Boolean logic used to interpret text in
> the query value. Valid values are:
>
> OR (Default) For example, a query value of capital of Hungary is
> interpreted as capital OR of OR Hungary.
>
> AND For example, a query
> value of capital of Hungary is interpreted as capital AND of AND
> Hungary.

When default analyzer ie standard used on text field, explain API returns below for search query

POST /{your-index}/_search?explain=true

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description": {
                            "query": "cat dog"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And search query with explain param

```
 "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.6931471,
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.6931471,
                            "description": "weight(description:cat in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 0.6931471,
                                    "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 2.2,
                                            "description": "boost",
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 0.6931472,
                                            "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": 1,
                                                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 2,
                                                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                                    "details": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 0.45454544,
                                            "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": 1.0,
                                                    "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 1.2,
                                                    "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 0.75,
                                                    "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 4.0,
                                                    "description": "dl, length of field",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 4.0,
                                                    "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                                    "details": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_shard": "[66329708][0]",
                "_node": "tMk7cyaBRSeJ8dxuSQdHRg",
                "_index": "66329708",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 0.6931471,
                "_source": {
                    "description": "Garfield the sleepy dog"
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.6931471,
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.6931471,
                            "description": "weight(description:dog in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 0.6931471,
                                    "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 2.2,
                                            "description": "boost",
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 0.6931472,
                                            "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": 1,
                                                    "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 2,
                                                    "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                                    "details": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 0.45454544,
                                            "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": 1.0,
                                                    "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 1.2,
                                                    "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 0.75,
                                                    "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 4.0,
                                                    "description": "dl, length of field",
                                                    "details": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "value": 4.0,
                                                    "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                                    "details": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

You can note that search terms used to search is `cat` and `dog`.

While if you use different analyzer like [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) and index mapping like below

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "description": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "keyword" // Note this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample data**

```
{
    "description" : "cat dog"
}

{
    "description" : "Garfield the sleepy dog"
}
```

And make below search call

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description": {
                            "query": "cat dog"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice in explain API below tokens are used to search

`"weight(description:cat dog in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",` As **you can see now `cat` and `dog` is not split as match query uses the same analyzer applied at index time which uses `keyword` analyzer in example and doesn't break tokens on whitespace.**

Comment: Thanks Opster. I understand the multiple "match" within "should" is also "OR". Can you provide an example with a different Analyzer on how they are different?

Comment: @Elye, explained it using the example, please take a took it was becoming very big, so omitted last search call response but you should be able to try it your self and hope this helps :)